# Vários Migrations no mesmo Banco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Utilizamos o mesmo banco MS SQL para diversas aplicações. Tenho conhecimento de que tal ação não é recomenda porém, infelizmente é o método que terá que se aplicado.

Trabalho com `code first` e cada vez que eu crio uma aplicação e tento executar um `migration` no meu banco, é gerado um código que aplica `drop` nas tabelas das outras aplicações.

Atualmente no meu `Package Manager Console` executo o `Update-Database -script` e ajusto manualmente ou até mesmo aplico o mesmo comando em um banco local e executo o código no meu banco MS SQL.

Existe algum modo de trabalhar simultaneamente com vários `migrations` sem haver interferência em outra aplicação caso as tabelas possuírem nomes diferentes?

Comment: O esquema de *Migrations* supõe que todas as tabelas de um determinado schema são de um sistema apenas. O correto seria uma separação de schemas, e as tabelas de outros sistemas aparecerem como views do schema em que há o sistema com o EF.

Comment: Acredito que o CodeFirst nao esta sendo usado corretamente na sua visao... DatabaseFirst talvez seria a melhor opção... voce tambem pode desabilitar o migrations... e ate mesmo falar quais clases voce quer fazer o migrations, ou se ele sera automatico quando iniciar o sistema... EF é bem dinamico.